# Using the same module in multiple files/modules

Tags: node.js, import, module, require

Let's say I need a promise module, and I am using it in multiple files, I include all those files in `app.js`. Do I have to use require the promise module in each of them? Is there a way to pass it to the imported module?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should put a `var Promise = require('bluebird')` statement at the top of every file that uses it. This is how node/commonjs express dependencies. Sometimes people react to this initially by wanting to go back to global variables and just require something in one file and have it be implicitly/globally available in every other file in their application, but as an industry we have had years and years on both approaches and explicit dependency stating via `require` makes dependency management more, well manageable, overall. This is especially true in the case of automated tooling (browserify, webpack, etc).

Comment: So this is what I should do `var Promise = require('bluebird')
var data = require('./google-spreadsheet-data')(Promise)`?

Comment: Nope. Just put `var Promise = require('bluebird')` at the top of every file that uses it.